# Does DOM searching occur faster if elements don't have IDs?

Tags: performance, dom

I have a page with countless thousands of elements. Will the browser work more efficiently (for example, getElementById) if I keep the number of elements with IDs to a minimum, or does it make no difference?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see? Writing a piece of test code that generates a page with a large number of elements shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError The short answer is probably because I'm not a "Professional software dude since 1983" :)  It's a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the DOM is loaded into a specialized tree-like data structure, and trees are designed for fast lookups.  So once the page is in memory, all the searches will be blazing fast. The loading/parsing would be faster if you had a smaller file size, i.e. no IDs=less chars=less
Bytes.  But once it's all loaded into memory, it shouldn't matter much.

It would also depend on the kind of algorithm that the browser's JavaScript engine implements for the getElementById() method.  I'm sure Chrome does it differently from IE or FF and vise versa.  I wouldn't worry about this part since you can't control how each vendor implements their browser.

The main point is, try and keep the file size smaller. Favor short node names and IDs over long ones because, after all, string matching is occurring at some step in the parsing/searching process.

Comment: For WebCore, at least, the key thing for performance is to make sure that each id only appears once (of course, anything else is invalid html... but that doesn't stop a lot of people). If you do that, lookup by id is O(1).